# keep most common factor levels in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I used the "dummies" package to create 42 dummy variables for the 42 levels of a factor variable in my data-frame.  Now I only want to keep the 5 dummies that represent the five most common factor levels.  I used:

```
counts <- colSums(dummy_variables)
rank <- sort(counts)
```

to figure out what those levels are, but now I want to be able to reference the most common ones and keep them in my data frame.  I am somewhat new to R - I just can't figure out the syntax to do this.

Comment: Why are you creating dummy variables and not just using a factor variable?

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the top 5 variables, and then subset only those columns.

```
rank <- sort(counts)[(length(counts)-4):length(counts)]
dummy_variables <- dummy_variables[names(dummy_variables) %in% names(rank)]
```

Or in one line as the commenter suggested,

```
dummy_variables[names(dummy_variables) %in% names(tail(sort(colSums(dummy_variables)),5))]
```

Comment: this would give you the bottom five. and you don't need the second like, just extract the names while you subset